# Is $\|\varphi\| = \|\varphi p\| + \|\varphi(1-p)\|$?.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $p \in M$ a central projection. Let $\varphi \in M$ be a normal functional and define new normal functionals $\varphi p $ and $\varphi(1-p)$ by $$(\varphi p)(m) = \varphi(pm), \quad (\varphi(1-p)) (m) = \varphi((1-p)m).$$

Is it true that
$$\|\varphi\| = \|\varphi p\| + \|\varphi(1-p)\|?$$

Clearly the inequality $\le $ holds. Is the other inequality true as well?

I tried to use the direct sum decomposition $M= pM\oplus (1-p)M$ but it didn't work.

I also tried the following: let $\epsilon >0$. Choose unit vectors $m,n\in M$  satisfying $m=pm$ and $n=(1-p)n$ with $\| p\varphi\|\le \epsilon + |\varphi(pm)|$ and $\|(1-p)\varphi\|\le \epsilon + |(1-p)\varphi(n)|$. Then I tried to use $m,n$ to construct a contractive vector to get a good estimate but couldn't find anything satisfying either.

If $\varphi$ is positive, this is obviously true, by the identity $\varphi(1)=\varphi(p)+\varphi(1-p)$.

Hence, we obtain the result for self-adjoint $\varphi$ as well.

---

Context question: I'm trying to understand (8') in the following from Takesaki's book "Theory of operator algebra I". Here $z_0$ is the unique central projection in the universal enveloping algebra $M^{**}$ such that $M_* = M^* z_0$. I can see that (9) holds.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE? What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Why are you interested in this problem? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I added some attempts.

Comment: @Andromeda Are you familiar with the polar decomposition of normal linear functionals?

Comment: @MaoWao No I am not. In fact, this question is inspired by Takesaki III.2 theorem 2.14 because I don't understand why $V= (V \cap M_*) \oplus_1 (V \cap M_*^\perp)$ holds and the polar decomposition is only treated two sections later, so I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $M$ is acting on the Hilbert space $H$. As $p$ is central for $M$, we have
\begin{align*}
\|x\xi\|^2&=\|pxp\xi\|^2+\|(1-p)x(1-p)\xi\|^2\\
&\leq\max\{\|px\|,\|(1-p)x\|\}(\|p\xi\|^2+\|(1-p)\xi\|^2)\\
&=\max\{\|px\|,\|(1-p)x\|\}\|\xi\|^2
\end{align*}
for $x\in M$ and $\xi\in H$. Thus $\|x\|\leq\max\{\|px\|,\|(1-p)x\|\}$. Equality is easily shown by considering vectors in $pH$ and $(1-p)H$.

Now let $x,y\in M$ with $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$ and $\phi(px)=\|\phi p\|$, $\phi((1-p)y)=\|\phi(1-p)\|$. Then
$$
|\phi(px+(1-p)y)|=|\phi p(x)+\phi(1-p)(y)|=\|\phi p\|+\|\phi(1-p)\|
$$
and $\|px+(1-p)y\|=\max\{\|px\|,\|(1-p)y\|\}\leq 1$. Thus $\|\phi\|\geq \|\phi p\|+\|\phi(1-p)\|$.

Comment: Thanks! I failed to realise that $\|px + (1-p)y\| \le 1$ if $x,y$ are contractive! Thanks so much!

Comment: Why can you assume that the supremum $\|\phi p\|$ is attained though?

Comment: By the Hahn-Banach functional, for an element $x$ of a Banach space $E$ there exists $\phi\in E^\ast$ with $\|\phi\|=1$ and $\phi(x)=\|x\|$. In this specific case you take the Banach space of normal linear functionals, which has $M$ as its dual. Alternatively you can also use that normal functionals are weak$^\ast$ continuous and the unit ball is weak$^\ast$ compact.

Comment: In any case, it doesn't matter to much. You can also use almost maximizers and carry some $\varepsilon$'s trhough the proof.

Comment: Yes, $\phi$ is fixed  though (so Hahn-Banach doesn't seem relevant), but I think that just carrying the $\epsilon$'s through will work. I'll check it in detail soon!

Comment: I can see that the notation was confusing. What I meant is to view $\phi p$ as the element of the Banach space and $x$ as the linear functional from the Hahn-Banach theorem. This works because $M$ is the continuous dual of $M_\ast$.

Comment: Ah yes I see. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Everything works out just fine. More generally, this is true for any central projection $p$ in any $C^*$-algebra $A$ and any $\varphi\in A^*$.